# How to scale an image in Fabric.js to ignore the aspect ratio?

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to add an image of wooden panelling to a fabric.js canvas which is designed to look like a room. I want the image of the wooden panelling to be stretched and teh aspect ratio to be ignored, so it covers the whole wall. However, the image is currently getting cropped. See the image here: [Image of cropped panelling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HpQs.jpg)

Can someone please help me?

```
const getPanelling = (hex) => {
  const imageSrc = self.$nuxt.$store.getters['component_data/data']('wallImgURL')

  var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
    mode: 'overlay',
    alpha: 0.7,
    color: hex
  })

  fabric.Image.fromURL(imageSrc, (image) => {
    image.filters.push(filter)
    image.applyFilters()
    image.type = 'wall'
    canvas.add(image)
    canvas.sendToBack(image)
  }, {
    top: ceilingHeight(),
    height: floorLevel() - ceilingHeight(),
    width: canvas.width,
    backgroundImageStretch: false, 
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    hoverCursor: 'default',
    selectable: false, // make this object not selectable
    originY: 'top',
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
image.width = wall.width * scaleX
image.height = wall.height * scaleY
image.top = wall.top
image.left = wall.left
canvas.renderAll()
```